# Pulling host list from ldapserach command from netgroup

Tags: bash, ldap

As i am learning bash, i have written a small code which is nothing but a simple `ldapsearch` query which lists all the`memberNisNetgroup` under `Infra_Global` netgroup.

I am pulling the list out of the netgroup and iterating over the list with a `for loop` which works fine. I am just curious if the below code which works fine can have an improvement from the `bash` standard.

Would appreciate any help on this.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
NTGRP=$(ldapsearch -h ldapServer -xLL -b "cn=Infra_Global,ou=Netgroup,ou=tdi,o=tdp" | awk '/^memberNisNetgroup/{print $2}'| cut -d"_" -f2-)
    
for netg in $NTGRP ;
    
do
echo "-- $netg --";
    
ldapsearch -h ldapServer -xLL -b "ou=Netgroup,ou=$netg,ou=location,ou=tdi,o=tdp" | awk '/,,/{print $2}' | tr -d '(),'
    
done
```

### Result:

```
---- SAT-GEN11 ----
inv0602.tdi.tdp.com
inv0557.tdi.tdp.com
```